Integer Optimization with Constraints
I need to maximize the following expressions: $mn-n^2$ given $0\lt m^2+n^2 < d$, where $d$ is given to me. I am also given that $m$ and $n$ are both integers and that $gcd(m, n) = 1$. I am unsure of how to proceed with this problem. I know that $m$ must be greater than $n$, and that they must be of opposing parities. I have looked into integer programming, but I am unsure of how to proceed with this optimization. I am permitted to use a computer program to solve this, but it must solve the problem relatively quickly (less than a minute for $d = 2*10^{18}$).

Please write where this problem comes from. It is considered bad style to ask for solutions to ProjectEuler problems online.

As your main objective is computer efficiency, I advise you to consider the following continuous setting (with correspondence: $x \leftrightarrow n, \ y \leftrightarrow m$):
How to maximize quantity:
$$q=yx-x^2 \tag{1}$$
under the following constraint:
$$0<x^2+y^2 \le d \ ? \tag{2}$$
(Please note that I have written (2) with an $\le$ instead of a $<$ for an easier handling).
(1) can be written
$$y=x+\frac{q}{x}\tag{1'}$$
Condition (2) means that the points must be in the disk centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{d}$.
Condition (1') can be interpreted, for a given $q$, as the equation of a hyperbola $(H_q)$, all of them sharing the same vertical asymptote $x=0$ and slant asymptote $y=x$.

Fig. 1 : Some hyperbolas $(H_q)$, one of them being the optimal one with point of tangency $(x_0,y_0)$ (in green) given by formulas (4).
Therefore, among all those "russian dolls" hyperbolas, a single one is tangent to the disk, as can be seen on at two symmetrical points of tangency  $\pm(x_0,y_0)$. An explicit formulation of $\pm(x_0,y_0)$ can be obtained with the technique of Lagrange multiplier. Do you know it ? See appendix below.

Now, coming back to the discrete setting, the optimal tuple $(n,m)$ is in the close vicinity of $(x_0,y_0)$. This is adapted for a computer approach, lowering drastically the number of points of $\mathbb{N^2}$ to be investigated (you should be in the "relatively quickly" range...).
Of course, a specific mathematical study using some kind of integer programming is surely possible, but it isn't in my "field of expertise"...
Appendix : Lagrange method amounts to  express that the gradients (obtained by computing partial derivatives) of the two curves with equations:
$$yx-x^2=q \ \ \text{and} \ \ x^2+y^2=d$$
are proportional at the point(s) of tangency. This gives rise to the system of three equations with 3 unknowns :
$$\begin{cases}y-2x&=&\lambda 2x\\x&=&\lambda 2y\\x^2+y^2&=&d\end{cases}\tag{3}$$
whose positive solutions are:
$$\begin{cases}
     x_0&=&e\\y_0&=&(1+\sqrt{2})e\end{cases} \ \text{with} \ e=\tfrac12\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{2})d}\tag{4}$$
(the value of $\lambda$ is unimportant). Please note that all potential minimization points lie on a same line.
Figure 1 has been generated by the following Sage program ; see in particular the last lines implementing the solution of system (3).
 var('x y d L a e')
 a=5
 d=2*(1+sqrt(2))
 g=line(((-a,0),(a,0)),color='black')
 g+=line(((0,-a),(0,a)),color='black')
 g+=line(((-a,-a),(a,a)),color='black')
 g+=implicit_plot(x^2+y^2-d,(x,-a,a),(y,-a,a),color='red')
 for k in range(1,6) :
    g+=implicit_plot(x*y-x^2-k,(x,-a,a),(y,-a,a))
 e=sqrt((2-sqrt(2))*d)/2
 g+=point((e,(1+sqrt(2))*e),color='green',size=50)
 show(g)
 s=solve([y-2*x==L*2*x,x==L*2*y,x^2+y^2==d],x,y,L)
 show(s)


Thank you! I used this and ended up solving it for d= 2*10^18. I have marked this as the accepted answer.
